# Nuxt3 recursive function results in error 500 (A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin...)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Hey so the title was too long, here is the full error message :

`A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug.`

I have a Nuxt3 component which sends a graphql request to fetch a content type named "Events" on my backoffice , it returns a maximum of 100 elements per requests due to graphql restrictions on the backend.

So I check if there is still more content to fetch and if so I send another request using a recursive function.

But when the recursive function is called by itself (meaning there are more elements to fetch) I get the error I mentionned above, however if there is 99 elements and there is no need to call the recursive function again everything works perfectly which is why I don't understand the reason for this error to exist.

Here is the code function

```
async function getMoreEvents(seasonId , endCursor , alreadyFetched) {

    const moreEvents = await useAsyncQuery(fetchMoreEvents , {
        id : seasonId,
        first : 100,
        after : endCursor,
    })

    let moreEventsFetched = moreEvents.data.value.saison.programmes.nodes

    if(alreadyFetched) {
        moreEventsFetched = [...alreadyFetched , ...moreEventsFetched]
    }

    if(moreEvents.data.value.saison.programmes.pageInfo.hasNextPage) { // checks if I need to rerun the graphql request to fetch more events
        const newEndCursor = moreEvents.data.value.saison.programmes.pageInfo.endCursor
        return  await getMoreEvents(seasonId , newEndCursor , moreEventsFetched) // if I comment this line I get no errors but I'll be missing some events

    } else {
        return moreEventsFetched
    }
}
```